# IDWriteFactory::CreateTextLayout method causes window to suddenly close

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

In the app that I'm building using the Windows API, I am currently working on writing text to the screen. I am trying to use the `CreateTextLayout` method, but with that particular function, I am running into problems that I can't figure out how to solve. When I just run my app, I starts fine and the just exits with no error warnings of any kind. Using breakpoints, I traced the issue to that function. Here is the code I am using to call it:

```
IDWriteFactory* writeFactory;
IDWriteTextFormat* writeTextFormat;
IDWriteTextLayout* writeTextLayout;

 HRESULT App::CreateDeviceIndependentResources()
{
    HRESULT hr;
// Create a Direct2D factory.
hr = D2D1CreateFactory(
    D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
    &writeFactory
);


if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = DWriteCreateFactory(
        DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
        __uuidof(writeFactory),
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&writeFactory)
    );

}

if (writeFactory == NULL)
        OutputDebugStringA("NULL\n");

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr =  writeFactory->CreateTextFormat(
        L"Times New Roman",
        NULL,
        DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
        DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
        DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
        14.0f,
        L"EN-US",
        &writeTextFormat
    );
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Create a DirectWrite text format object.
    hr = writeFactory->CreateTextLayout(
        L"Projects",      // The string to be laid out and formatted.
        8,  // The length of the string.
        writeTextFormat,  // The text format to apply to the string (contains font information, etc).
        10.0f,         // The width of the layout box.
        10.0f,        // The height of the layout box.
        &writeTextLayout  // The IDWriteTextLayout interface pointer.
    );
}
}
```

I feel like this is pretty basic becuase I just followed the tutorial on Microsoft.com; however, something is clearly wrong. My guess is that it could be related to `writeTextFormat`. It is an `IDWriteTextFormat` object. Additionally, all of these objects are initialized in the `CreateDeviceIndependentResources()` functions. Should I initialize them elsewhere?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `writeTextFormat`? You need first create an `IDWriteTextFormat` interface object by using the `IDWriteFactory::CreateTextFormat` method. If it still doesn't work, please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is also necessary to check the return value of [CreateTextLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefactory-createtextlayout#return-value).

Comment: I just checked and `writeTextFactory` is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse the use of `D2D1CreateFactory` and `DWriteCreateFactory`.

`D2D1CreateFactory` is used to create the `ID2D1Factory` interface, which is used to create an `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` and an `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` to render text.

`DWriteCreateFactory` is used to create an `IDWriteFactory` interface, which is the root factory interface for all `DirectWrite` objects. And the `DirectWrite` objects are used to format the text.

Such as:

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRT_;
...

pRT_->DrawText(
    wszText_,        // The string to render.
    cTextLength_,    // The string's length.
    pTextFormat_,    // The text format.
    layoutRect,       // The region of the window where the text will be rendered.
    pBlackBrush_     // The brush used to draw the text.
    );
```

Maybe you can start from [Part 2: Create Device Independent Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/getting-started-with-directwrite#part-2-create-device-independent-resources).

Some code:

```
IDWriteFactory* pDWriteFactory_;

hr = DWriteCreateFactory(
       DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
       __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
       reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pDWriteFactory_)
       );
...

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Create a DirectWrite text format object.
    hr = pDWriteFactory_->CreateTextLayout(
        L"Projects",      // The string to be laid out and formatted.
        8,  // The length of the string.
        writeTextFormat,  // The text format to apply to the string (contains font information, etc).
        10.0f,         // The width of the layout box.
        10.0f,        // The height of the layout box.
        &writeTextLayout  // The IDWriteTextLayout interface pointer.
    );
}
```

Official example: [HelloWorld](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/DirectWrite/HelloWorld)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. On a related note, do you have any guesses why the `m_pRenderTarget->DrawTextLayout(origin, writeTextLayout, m_pBlackBrush, D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_NONE)` function would do nothing at all?

Comment: @johndoe `DrawTextLayout` is works for me. Have you checked all the parameters in `DrawTextLayout?` Note: [Drawing operations](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/fe45388171f3bfef7866f654cbac588fbb6c9f52/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/DirectWrite/HelloWorld/MultiformattedText.cpp#L422) can only be issued between a `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` call.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I forgot the `BeginDraw`